# Modifying the res class to have less whitespace

Tags: spacing, cv, resume

I am currently in the process of creating my CV. The `res` template I found online seems to do the trick. But I am having some troubles.

The picture below kind of highlights what I want to do.

[image: myimage]

So basically, I'd like to move the education information below the education title. This will let the lines look longer and look less busy. Furthermore, and I am not sure if this warrants a another question, but a simple `\begin{itemize}` looks very out of context in my "online courses".

Here is a MW code:

```
% LaTeX resume using res.cls
\documentclass[line,margin,11pt]{res} 
%\usepackage{helvetica} % uses helvetica postscript font (download helvetica.sty)
%\usepackage{newcent}   % uses new century schoolbook postscript font 


\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newcommand{\sbt}{\,\begin{picture}(-1,1)(-1,-3)\circle*{3}\end{picture}\ }
\begin{document}

\name{my  name}
 % \address used twice to have two lines of address
\address{address}
\address{ phone , email}

\begin{resume}

\section{OBJECTIVE} A position in the field of computers with special 
                interests in business applications programming, 
                information processing, and management systems. 


\section{EDUCATION} {\sl Master of Science,} Applied Mathematics (in progress) \\ 
                            {\bf York University, Toronto, ON}  \\
                            \underline{Research} Modelling transcription factor binding sites using combinatorial histone code as a background model. \\
                            \underline{Relevent Courses} \\
                            \begin{itemize*}

                            \item[\sbt]     Functional Analysis (A) 
                            \item[\sbt]  Computational Methods in Mathematical Biology (A+) 
                            \item[\sbt]  Practicum in Applied Mathematics (A+) 
                            \item[\sbt]  Probability Models (B+) 
                            \item[\sbt]  Partial Differential Equations (B+) 
                            \item[\sbt]  Mathematical Modelling (B)  
                            \item[\sbt]  Measure Theory (Audit)
                            \item[\sbt]  Probability Theory (Audit) 
                            \end{itemize*} \\ \\
{\sl Bachelor of Science,} Applied Mathematics \\
                % \sl will be bold italic in New Century Schoolbook (or
            % any postscript font) and just slanted in
        % Computer Modern (default) font
                {\bf York University, Toronto, ON} \\
                \underline{Concentration}: Numerical Analysis and Differential Mathematics. \\
                 \\
        {\sl Diploma,} Computer Science \\ 
                % \sl will be bold italic in New Century Schoolbook (or
            % any postscript font) and just slanted in
        % Computer Modern (default) font
                {\bf Seneca College, Toronto, ON} \\
                \underline{Languages} Visual Basic, Python, C, C++, .NET, SQL, HTML and DBA.  \\
                Proficient in Mathematical programming using MATLAB, R and SAS/SPSS.

                {\sl Massive open online courses} \\
                \begin{itemize}
                \item Bioinformatics: Introduction and Methods {\sl Peking University, China} \\
                \item Bioinformatics: Life Sciences on your Computer  {\sl Johns Hopkins University, USA} \\
                \item Modelling and Simulation using MATLAB (certificate recieved) {\sl Prof Dr. -Ing Georg Fries} 
                \end{itemize}
```

I've found the `\sbt` to have my horizontal lists. So please keep this in mind. As it does do "something" with the "environment".

Comment: Please see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `\\` as a line or paragraph break, *especially* to separate `\item`s. Just leave a blank line between elements.

[image]

```
% LaTeX resume using res.cls
\documentclass[line,margin]{res} 

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\name{my name}
 % \address used twice to have two lines of address
\address{address}
\address{phone, email}

\begin{resume}

\section{OBJECTIVE}
  A position in the field of computers with special 
  interests in business applications programming, 
  information processing, and management systems. 

\section{EDUCATION}

  {\slshape Master of Science,} Applied Mathematics (in progress)

  {\bfseries York University, Toronto, ON}

  \underline{Research} Modelling transcription factor binding sites using combinatorial histone code as a background model.

  \underline{Relevent Courses}

  \begin{itemize*}[label=\textbullet]
    \item Functional Analysis (A) 
    \item Computational Methods in Mathematical Biology (A+) 
    \item Practicum in Applied Mathematics (A+) 
    \item Probability Models (B+) 
    \item Partial Differential Equations (B+) 
    \item Mathematical Modelling (B)  
    \item Measure Theory (Audit)
    \item Probability Theory (Audit) 
  \end{itemize*}

  {\slshape Bachelor of Science,} Applied Mathematics

  {\bfseries York University, Toronto, ON}

  \underline{Concentration}: Numerical Analysis and Differential Mathematics.

  {\slshape Diploma,} Computer Science

  {\bfseries Seneca College, Toronto, ON}

  \underline{Languages} Visual Basic, Python, C, C++, .NET, SQL, HTML and DBA.

  Proficient in Mathematical programming using MATLAB, R and SAS/SPSS.

  {\slshape Massive open online courses}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Bioinformatics: Introduction and Methods {\slshape Peking University, China}
    \item Bioinformatics: Life Sciences on your Computer  {\slshape Johns Hopkins University, USA}
    \item Modelling and Simulation using MATLAB (certificate recieved) {\slshape Prof Dr.~-Ing Georg Fries} 
  \end{itemize}

\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay thanks. I am not particulary fond of leaving a line break every line. I'd like to group my schools/degrees together. But I'll stop using `\\`. Also do you know how to move it below the "education" title and have it span the entire width?

Comment: @masfenix: If you like to group things together, then do so and use an explicit `\par` rather than ``\\``.

Comment: @masfenix: If you want the layout to be different, my suggestion is to avoid the [`res` class](http://ctan.org/pkg/resume) and set it in `article` instead.

Comment: Do you have any templates? I feel like I am not good enough to create one by myself

Comment: @masfenix: Have you taken a look at [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv)?